# Slack reminder - 1st Friday of every month

Tags: slack

Please can someone advise if I am able to set a reminder for the first Friday of every month in Slack without having to add a date so for example:-

/remind #channel It's time for another Monthly Board Update on the first Monday of every month at 10:00am

Comment: Have you tried something like : "/remind me to do whatever on the 1st friday of every month".

Comment: I might just set one reminder and then include in my reminder a task to create another reminder.... at least for monthly stuff.

Answer (score 1):

(A) create a new google calendar and [set your dates](https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/1187834/how-i-do-create-repeat-event-on-last-friday-of-every-month-the-4th-doesn-t-work-when-5-fridays?hl=en). Then [connect that google calendarto slack](https://slack.com/help/articles/206329808-Google-Calendar-for-Slack)

(B) However, I'd personally prefer to use a yearly calendar and use copy-paste to set a reminder for each specific date: it allows me to avoid setting them on public holidays, or too close to new year's eve etc. It probably takes less than 10 minutes to do that for a two-year period.

(C) You also might want to look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1037708/slackbot-how-to-set-a-reminder-for-last-wednesday-of-the-month-or-last-day-of-th)

Comment: Can you give an example for B?

Answer (score 0):

The closest I've found is

```
/remind monthly "Message" at 10:00am
```

However, this is for the 1st, which may or may not be a Friday (but it's at least close)